# JSON Serialize error in python :raise TypeError(repo(o) + "is not JSON serializable")

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization, set

I have a function that returns output in the form :

Result is:

```
outputs {
 key: "output"
 value {
 dtype: DT_FLOAT
 tensor_shape {
 }
 float_val: -3.33661770821
 }
}
```

And i would like to jsonify this output . But when i try this way

```
def ss():
    ........
    return jsonify({'result':result})
```

It sends error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
       raise TypeError(repo(o) + "is not JSON serializable")
TypeError:outputs {
     key: "output"
     value {
     dtype: DT_FLOAT
     tensor_shape {
     }
     float_val: -3.33661770821
     }
    }
```

How do i jsonify the above output? or I want to take the Float_val value alone.

Comment: What's the type and value of `result`? That thing you posted isn't a valid dictionary, and it can't be a string because strings are JSON serializable.

Comment: This is _probably_ a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable), but let's wait for an [mcve]...

Comment: I don't know the type of result. I thought it was dictionary.But it's not. This link here https://weiminwang.blog/2017/09/12/introductory-guide-to-tensorflow-serving/ has the same output type.

Comment: I got the answer myself. Its a protocol message from tensorflow that needs to be converted to json. I used google protocol package to convert this message to JSON. Reference: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.json_format-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the Tensorflow protocol message to JSON by using

```
from google.protobuf import json_format

message = my_proto_pb2.MyMessage(foo='bar')
json_string = json_format.MessageToJson(message)
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.json_format-module